# Regex to extract key surrounded by brackets

Tags: python, regex

```
a = "[abc]def - aaa"      # key = "abc" value = "def - aaa"
a2 = "[_abc def]def - aaa"  # key = "_abc def" value = "def - aaa"
b = "[abc]"
c = "abc]"                 # key = "abc"   value = ""
d = "[abc]]def/acd"       # key = "abc"   value = "def/acd"
f = "abc]]"               # key = "abc" value = ""
```

Above are just some examples of the patterns. I have thousands of similar string variables. Bracket may be  single `"]", "["` or double `"]]", "[["`, or missing in the left side.

What I want is to get the key value pair. The key is the string inside the bracket (left bracket may be missing) (e.g., `abc`, `abc def`). The value is the string in the right of the bracket such as `def - aaa` or `def/acd` or empty string.

How to define the regex pattern in Python? I tried a few but they do not work for all variables.

I tried `re.search(r"([^[].*?)(?:]|]])([^]].*)", a)` but it does not work with `re.search(r"([^[].*?)(?:]|]])([^]].*)", b)`

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: What are you expecting from these examples? What should `"abc]]"` produce for example?

Comment: @dawg I update my question, for `"abc]]"`   `key = abc` and `value = ""`

Comment: The revised version of the question with examples is interesting and non-trivial. Doesn't deserve downvotes or VtC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to ignore brackets, then you can use this:

```
words = re.split('[\[\]]+', key_value)
words = filter(None, words)          # remove empty words
key = words[0]
value = words[1] if len(words) > 1 else None
```

This pattern was copied from the documentation: [re — Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I just updated my question to make it clear

Answer (score 2):

Peronally I would do it using .index(), but you asked for an regexp, so here you are.

```
>>> expr = r"^(?:\[?)(.*?)\]+(.*?)$"
>>> re.search(expr, a).group(0, 1, 2)
('[abc]def - aaa', 'abc', 'def - aaa')
>>> re.search(expr, a2).group(0, 1, 2)        
('[_abc def]def - aaa', '_abc def', 'def - aaa')
>>> re.search(expr, b).group(0, 1, 2)
('[abc]', 'abc', '')
>>> re.search(expr, c).group(0, 1, 2)
('abc]', 'abc', '')
>>> re.search(expr, d).group(0, 1, 2)
('[abc]]def/acd', 'abc', 'def/acd')
>>> re.search(expr, f).group(0, 1, 2)         
('abc]]', 'abc', '')
```

See the "Match information" section on the right sidebar [here](https://regex101.com/r/tS1dU5/1).

Answer (score 1):

I would use rpartition here:

```
txt='''\
[abc]def - aaa
[_abc def]def - aaa
[abc]
abc]
[abc]]def/acd
abc]]'''

import re

for e in txt.splitlines():
    li=e.rpartition(']')
    key=re.search(r'([^\[\]]+)', li[0]).group(1)
    value=li[-1]
    print '{:20}=> "{}":"{}"'.format(e,key, value)
```

If you *want* to use a regex, you can use:

```
for e in txt.splitlines():
    m=re.search(r'\[*([^\[\]]+)\]*(.*)', e)
    print '{:20}=> "{}":"{}"'.format(e,*m.groups())
```

In either case, prints:

```
[abc]def - aaa      => "abc":"def - aaa"
[_abc def]def - aaa => "_abc def":"def - aaa"
[abc]               => "abc":""
abc]                => "abc":""
[abc]]def/acd       => "abc":"def/acd"
abc]]               => "abc":""
```